# UML diagram for basic Rails classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, uml

Where I can find UML for RoR itself? with ActiveRecord etc classes. 
If there is no one, advise me how to make it faster and better. I just should read sources or some other thing?

Comment: Hi @homakov, what do you mean by UML for ROR itself. Coz UML is a standard which used to design/ modeling systems. ROR is a framework which used to build systems ontop. could u explain your question little more..

Comment: but it is software as well. I need UML for ror's classes: activerecord, activesupport etc with methods

Answer (score 0):

not sure for ROR itself but you can check [RailsRoad](http://railroad.rubyforge.org/) for generating your app's UML

Answer (score 0):

If your app is Rails 3, use the `RailsRoady` gem instead.  You can find it [here](https://github.com/preston/railroady).